# How to manipulate Hyper-V from C# on Windows Nano Server

Tags: c#, .net-core, hyper-v, nano-server

As I can see there is no way to use WMI in C# since System.Automation is not supported in .NET Core.

What is a proper way to manipulate Hyper-V from C# on Windows Nano Server?(For ex: get list of virtual machines)

Comment: Why don't you use Powershell? You'd have to use the same commands with System.Automation

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos And what about the information on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/powershell-on-nano-server) page?

Comment: @JeroenHeier that page says that *Powershell itself* is built on top of .NET Core. Powershell isn't a wrapper over WMI, so it doesn't need System.Automation.